# How to implement search functionality to custom listview implemented by Volley

Tags: android

Dear Android developers,

I created a custom listview containing image, and texts now i want to apply as search functionality to the custom listview. I have searched the internet and the results i found are not specific to volley.

Please help me or send me a link that shows how to implement a search functionality specifically to a custom listview implemented by Volley.

I developed the volley custom listview from the android hive tutorial !. now i want to add a search functionality to the lsitview. Help me please am stuck

Comment: Search functionality not related particularly with Volley. You need to store your all data in `Hashmap` arraylist and filter out your data from that list while searching. You can also implement your custom adapter with `Filter`.

Comment: Oh thank you very Much. So from my understanding i have to store all of my data to arraylist then i will fill my listview from my arrray adapter, finally i can implement the search functionality Right? There are a lot of tutorials that shows how to store data to arraylist but am not sure which one is the best one. Can you send me a link that shows how thats done clearly... Tnx